# Cannot access a closed stream when passing stream to another function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stream, filestream, memorystream

I need to pass a stream to a couple of functions in another class, but its throwing an error

> Cannot access a closed stream

Here's the code:

first method:

Here it opens a file with File.Open method and then creates a memorystream object and it copies FileStream to MemoryStream. then sets Position to 0 (i set position to 0, because i was that in a solution, but not helping tho). Then it creates an object of class `DocxConvert` and call the `Converto` method by passing MemoryStream to it.

```
    using (var stream = File.Open(tempPath2, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                using (var docx = new DocxConvert())
                {
                    return docx.Converto(ms);
                }
            }
    }
```

DocxConvert Class:

It takes stream and then calls `copyStream` method by passing the accepted stream.

copyStream method in DocxConvert Class: it should copy the accepted stream to another stream called `_memoryStream` which is a class property.

```
    public class DocxConvert
{  

        private MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

  public bool Converto(Stream stream)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        copyStream(stream);
                        //more code
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    }

                    return true;
                }


       private void copyStream(Stream stream)
        {
            stream.CopyTo(_memoryStream); //here it throws the error
        }
}
```

**p.s. I search for this error here before posting, but non of the topics helped me.**

> SOLVED by restarting PC, the code it ok.

Comment: I don't understand what your code demonstrates. Could you create a [mcve]? Either way, if you're getting that exception, it's because you have closed the stream at some point, or passed the stream to a method that closed it.

Comment: It appears to be `_memoryStream` that isn't open at the time of the error.

Comment: @John I updated the topic, by adding some explenation of what it does

Comment: The MemoryStream you are passing to `Convertto` is a different one to `_memoryStream` though? Where does `_memoryStream` come from?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError no because, i've tried also to call `stream.Position = 0` before that `stream.CopyTo()`, and the error was being threw in that line, which means `stream` for a particular reason isnt open

Comment: @John Converto method accepts the one that is being send by the first method at the beginning. Than that same one is passed to `copyStream` where it tries to copy that accepted stream to a class property. Check the updated code now

Comment: @John here i made a little version of what is code like, so you can try on your own http://rextester.com/live/NGMG37032

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware about your question .But here in the code bellow no excepion

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tempPath2 = Application.StartupPath + "//" + "test.txt";
        using (var stream = File.Open(tempPath2, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;

                var docx = new DocxConvert();
                    var isok = docx.Converto(ms);

            }
        }
    }
```

The bellow is the calss defined where _memorystream is defined at top

```
    MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    public bool Converto(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            copyStream(stream);
            //more code
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
          //  Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return true;
    }
    private void copyStream(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            stream.CopyTo(_memoryStream); 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. All I did was to restart my PC and its working now. Didnt know why that even happened

Comment: OK Thanks and enjoy